# Using generating functions to construct or solve differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, intuition, constructive-mathematics, chebyshev-polynomials

I know that $T_n(x)$ is the solution of the differential equation $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+n^2y=0$, where
$$
T_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
T_n(x)=1 & \text{if $n=0$}\\
T_n(x)=x & \text{if $n=1$}\\
T_{n}(x)=2xT_{n-1}(x)- T_{n-2}(x) & \text{if $n\geq 2$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
this can be proved using power series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_equation).

I was wondering if there is a way to go "backwards", given any recurrence (as a generating function) $f_n$, can I construct a differential equation such that $f_n$ is a solution of the constructed equation?.

For example, we know that $$T_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n} {2},$$
How can I construct $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+n^2y=0$ given that $y(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n} {2}$ is a solution of that equation?.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: One way is too compute few derivatives of the function and see if they satisfy an algebraic relation. In fact, this amounts to showing that the function and some of its derivatives are linearly dependent. This is not easy in general but can still be done.